# How to Show Trend Lines in Visual Web Developer

Tags: c#, charts, visual-web-developer, trendline

I have just started to work with Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.  I have seen examples of charts that show trend lines but I can't find any way to do this myself.  I am using C#.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a way to dynamically create interactive charts for the web or Windows forms applications, the quickest way to get started would probably be to check out mschart:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Microsoft has a downloadable projects that you build in Visual Studio to guide you through how to use the chart control.  It's awesome, so I hope that's what you're looking for!

Here's the downloads page, where you can get the project files for either web or winforms:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx